# How to write subquery in select list in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
Select *,
    (Select DefaultStartDay from Scheduler.ProgramSettings ps where ps.DefaultStartDay = s.Id )  [DefaultStartDay]
from Scheduler.Schedules s
where ScheduleType = 2;
```

I want to write above SQL query in EF Core, Specially I need subquery in select list to get data from another table with specific condition.

please refer image.[Sample Data with SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBUQ.png)

I have tried below EF Core but getting wrong result.

```
var model = _context.Schedules
            .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == 2)
            .Select(rv => new ProgramSetting
             {
               Id = rv.Id,
               ProgramTemplateId = rv.ProgramTemplateId,
               IsActive = rv.IsActive,
               DefaultStartDay = rv.Id
             }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is a misuse of EF Core and LINQ.  EF isn't a replacement for SQL, it's an ORM. Its job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables, not allow you to write SQL queries in C#

Comment: Besides, that SQL will fail if there's more than 1 result from the subquery. Even in SQL you'd need a different query. A simple `INNER JOIN` on `ps.DefaultStartDay = s.Id` would return the same results. In EF Core, if the `Schedule` type has a `ProgramSettings` property, you'd only have to write `_context.Schedules.Where(s => s.ScheduleType == 2)`. If you want to eagerly load the settings, add `.Include(sch=>sch.ProgramSettings)`. If you only need some properties from either class, you can eliminate `Include` as `Select` will cause EF to generate that JOIN

Comment: I won't go too far as first comment by @Panagiotis, but `ProgramSettings` table and `DefaultStartDay` in the SQL subquery sound like FK relationship, isn't it? EF Core has special way of representing relationships called navigation properties, so you don't need to write explicit subqueries or joins when accessing such tables inside the LINQ query. With that in mind, if you want a concrete answer, show the 2 classes involved, not tables, SQL queries or results.

Comment: @IvanStoev trying to translate SQL to LINQ is like trying to hammer a bolt. First you need to tell people to stop doing this and use a spanner or ratchet, then you explain the cases where it's OK to use a hammer.

Comment: It's not so bad for me to use LINQ to Entities for queries, @Panagiotis. While it is not a full replacement, it has most of the capabilities needed to query the database via C#. After all, why they bother to support/translate LINQ if it is not supposed to be used. In fact, even though they lack window functions and some other "advanced" SQL features, for some type of queries it offers better readability/understanding of how get the desired result shape than the flat SQL. Another point is that the (at least initial, I know it has been killed with introduction of `IQueryable`) idea is to let...

Comment: @IvanStoev I didn't say using LINQ to Entities is bad. Trying to blindly convert SQL queries to LINQ though results in big problems for even simple queries, as most EF Core questions show.

Comment: ...people write queries against everything w/o knowing SQL or other specific languages. Finally, if there is functionality provided by a tool/library, I won't limit myself, nor the people using it. For EF Core, all I want is to let people use navigation properties whenever possible, and resort to pure LINQ and raw SQL only when really needed.

Comment: @Panagiotis I fully agree with your last comment. May be I misunderstood  your point, in which case I apologize.

Comment: @IvanStoev the first comment was the equivalent of "stop hammering that bolt before you break something". I haven't come up with a short way to say all this in a single comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query is wrong and this is a misuse of EF Core.

First, that SQL will fail if there's more than 1 result from the subquery. Even in SQL you'd need a different query. An INNER JOIN would return the same results without failing if there are multiple matches.

```
Select s.*,ps.DefaultStartDay 
from Scheduler.Schedules s
    inner join Scheduler.ProgramSettings ps on ps.DefaultStartDay = s.Id
where ScheduleType = 2;
```

Second, using LINQ to emulate SQL is a misuse of both EF Core and LINQ. EF isn't a replacement for SQL, it's an ORM. Its job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables, not allow you to write SQL queries in C#

It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs as needed from the relations between entities (not tables). In this case, if `Schedule` has a `ProgramSettins` property, EF would generate the necessary joins automatically. Loading an entire schedule object could be as simple as :

```
var schedules=_context.Schedules
                      .Incule(sch=>sch.ProgramSettings)
                      .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == 2)
                      .ToArray();
```

`Include` is used to eagerly load the settings, not to force a JOIN.

If a `Select` clause is used that requires a property from ProgramSettings, the JOIN will be generated automatically, eg :

```
var namesAndDays=_context.Schedules
                      .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == 2)
                      .Select(s=>new { 
                          Name = s.Name,
                          StartDay = s.ProgramSettings.DefaultStartDay 
                      })
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: By taking your query's help I got my result by editing little git.  ```var namesAndDays = _context.Schedules
                       .Where(s => s.ScheduleType == 2)
                       .Select(s => new {
                           Name = s.Name,
                           Id = _context.ProgramSettings.Select(d => d.DefaultStartDay == s.Id).FirstOrDefault()
                       })
                       .ToArray();```

Comment: @AbuzarAnsari I didn't understand the comment. The whole point is that the original SQL was wrong, didn't return the 1st default day but threw an error if there were more than 1, and you don't need subqueries because EF deals with objects, not subqueries

Comment: @AbuzarAnsari are multiple settings allowed or not? It they aren't, `ProgramSettings` is a single object and the query I posted already does what you want. If multiple are allowed, `ProgramSettings` should be a collection and you'll have to write `s.ProgramSettings.Select(ps=>ps.DefaultStartDay).FirstOrDefault()`. That will return essentially a random day though, so you need to add an `OrderBy` clause to get repeatable results. You didn't post the classes, tables or sample data, so one can only guess